# Why is my addEventListener null for my navigation bar icon in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react app that has a navigation bar at the top and on the right is a hamburger icon, that when clicked, a drop-down menu appears with the links leading to other pages of the site.

When a link is clicked, the drop-down should collapse and would load the other page.

It does work, but the `link.addEventListener` is always being null for some reason and I can't really pinpoint why exactly. And sometimes the whole react app crashes because of it.

```
const toggleNav = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
const navLink = document.querySelectorAll("#navLink");

toggleNav.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.body.classList.add('hamburger-open');
    // document.body.classList.remove('hamburger-open');
    
})

navLink.forEach(link => {
    if(link){
        link.addEventListener('click', () => {
            document.body.classList.remove('hamburger-open');
        })
    }
})
```

Help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do yo mean by *link.addEventListener is always being null*?  It's not supposed to return anything. Where are you seeing this?

Comment: It's not clear what problem you're trying to describe, or how React is in any way related.  Can you update this to a [mcve] as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) which demonstrates the problem, and indicate specifically what problem you are observing?

Comment: I assume you mean `link` is `null` and so you get an error trying to run `link.addEventListener`. That means there was no match for the selector. See the linked question for details. If you're using React, you usually wouldn't add an event listener via `addEventListener` at all (and you wouldn't look up an element via `querySelector`), so that may be the problem. The section on [event handling](https://react.dev/learn/responding-to-events) in the React docs may be useful.

Comment: I think you not persisting the component (Navbar) when you redirect the user the next page, If you doing that, then react renders the entire page, and when you try to access the elements at that time, by using document.querySelector, it would probably raise an error, because the page is not rendered yet, and the elements are not available in the dom tree. Make the navbar persistent across the entire application.

Comment: As @T.J.Crowder said, this is not the right way access the elements in the DOM, but if you truly need to, in that case that a look at useRef documentation from react